Cannot handle errors using formidable in node.js
I'm using node.js formidable to upload files to my express server.
I want to be able to handle some of the errors, like a file wasn't chosen, the file size outside of the limit, file type check etc. and the be able to return a specific error to the client based on the result.
But I just can't seem to find the right\a good way to do this?
I'm trying to do this in form.parse() but I'm having issues here because it stops processing the file if it exceeds the file limits? this means I can't do any kind of check as there is no data in file.uploaded?
This is my code:
app.post('/putdata', async (req, res, error) => {

    let fileUploaded = '';
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({

        //* Set up incoming data requirments
        maxFileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        minFileSize: 1,

    });

    console.log('Max file size allowed : ' + form.options.minFileSize);
    console.log('Min file size allowed : ' + form.options.maxFileSize);

    const uploaded = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

    
        //* Handle no file uploaded
        if(!files.uploaded) {
            console.log('file not selected.')
            res.status(400).send('No file recieved for upload');
            return;
        } 

        if (err) {
            console.log('error : ' + err)
            return;
        }

        fileUploaded = 'complete';
        resolve(true);
    });

    });
    console.log(fileUploaded);

});

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks for any help\suggestions.

I see the following key issues in your code:

Error handling order: Checking files.uploaded before processing err can miss critical errors, such as file size limitation.
Promise management: Errors not resolving or rejecting a promise, leading to a potential request hang.
File type validation: No validation of acceptable file types.

Improved solution:

Use promises with proper error handling: Ensure that all possible errors are caught and the promise is either allowed or rejected appropriately.
Check file types: Check the MIME type of the uploaded file to allow only certain types.
Send responses properly: Ensure that each execution path sends a response to prevent requests from hanging.

Revised Code Example:
app.post('/putdata', async (req, res) => {
   const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
      maxFileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, // 1 MB
      keepExtensions: true,
   });

   const allowedMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'];

   const parseForm = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
         if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
               return reject({status: 413, message: 'File size exceeds 1MB limit.'});
            }
            return reject({status: 400, message: err.message});
         }

         const uploadedFile = files.uploaded;
         if (!uploadedFile) {
            return reject({status: 400, message: 'No file received for upload.'});
         }

         if (!allowedMimeTypes.includes(uploadedFile.mimetype)) {
            return reject({status: 400, message: 'Invalid file type uploaded.'});
         }

         resolve({fields, files});
      });

      form.on('error', (err) => {
         console.error('Formidable error:', err);
      });
   });

   try {
      const {files} = await parseForm();
      console.log('File uploaded:', files.uploaded);
      res.status(200).json({message: 'File uploaded successfully.', file: files.uploaded});
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Upload error:', error);
      res.status(error.status || 500).json({error: error.message || 'Internal Server Error'});
   }
});


This is great, I am now able to understand how to do some proper error handling here with this example. Error handling isn't really my strong point as I mainly code for myself, but I'm trying to be a better person! :)

Okay, I'm glad I helped you
